# Batch process to delete table from SQL Server backup files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I have a set of full backups from a same SQL Server database saved in different files. For example:

- 01.my-database.bak
- 02.my-database.bak
- 03.my-database.bak

I want to delete a specific table from those files to save disk space. There is a batch process to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't edit the contents of backup files in this way.  You should either compress the backup files or archive them to a different server or storage medium if you require them to be kept.